# Stack bar-chart intersected between each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code for the stack bar chart

```
cols = ['Bug Prediction','Traceability','Security', 'Program Generation & Repair',
        'Performance Prediction','Code Similarity & Clone Detection',
        'Code Navigation & Understanding', 'Other_SE'] 
count_ANN = [2.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,3.0,5.0,1.0] 
count_CNN = [1.0,0.0,5.0,0.0,1.0,4.0,4.0,0.0]
count_RNN = [1.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,4.0,7.0,2.0] 
count_LSTM =[3.0,0.0,5.0,3.0,1.0,9.0,15.0,1.0]
count_GNN = [0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,3.0,3.0,3.0] 
count_AE =  [0.0,0.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,6.0,11.0,0.0]
count_AM =  [2.0,0.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,4.0,15.0,1.0]
count_other =[1.0,0.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,1.0,3.0,0.0]
b_RNN = list(np.add(count_ANN,count_CNN))
b_LSTM = list(np.add(np.add(count_ANN,count_CNN),count_RNN))
b_AE = list(np.add(np.add(np.add(count_ANN,count_CNN),count_RNN),count_AE))
b_GNN = list(np.add(b_AE,count_GNN))
b_others = list(np.add(b_GNN,count_other))
plt.bar(cols,count_ANN,0.4,label = "ANN")
plt.bar(cols,count_CNN,0.4,bottom=count_ANN,label = "CNN")
plt.bar(cols,count_RNN,0.4,bottom=b_RNN,label = "RNN")
plt.bar(cols,count_LSTM,0.4,bottom =b_LSTM, label = "LSTM")
plt.bar(cols,count_AE,0.4,bottom=b_AE,label = "Auto-Encoder")
plt.bar(cols,count_GNN,0.4,bottom=b_GNN,label = "GNN")
plt.bar(cols,count_other,0.4,bottom=b_others,label = "Others")
#ax.bar(cols, count)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(cols))+0.1,cols)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Then the output for this is overlapped stacks as in the following figure
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific problem is that `b_AE` is calculated wrong. (Also, there is a list called `count_AM` for which there is no label).

The more general problem, is that calculating all these values "by hand" is very prone to errors and difficult to adapt when there are changes.  It helps to write things in a loop.

The magic of numpy's [broadcasting and vectorization](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) lets you initialize `bottom` as a single zero, and then use numpy's adding to add the counts.

To have a bit neater x-axis, you can put the individual words on separate lines. Also, `plt.tight_layout()` tries to make sure all text fits nicely into the plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cols = ['Bug Prediction', 'Traceability', 'Security', 'Program Generation & Repair',
        'Performance Prediction', 'Code Similarity & Clone Detection',
        'Code Navigation & Understanding', 'Other_SE']
count_ANN = [2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 1.0]
count_CNN = [1.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 0.0]
count_RNN = [1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 7.0, 2.0]
count_LSTM = [3.0, 0.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0, 9.0, 15.0, 1.0]
count_GNN = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
count_AE = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 6.0, 11.0, 0.0]
count_AM = [2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 4.0, 15.0, 1.0]
count_other = [1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0]

all_counts = [count_ANN, count_CNN, count_RNN, count_LSTM, count_GNN, count_AE, count_AM, count_other]
all_labels = ["ANN", "CNN", "RNN", "LSTM", "GNN", "Auto-Encoder", "AM", "Others"]

cols = ["\n".join(c.split(" ")) for c in cols]
cols = [c.replace("&\n", "& ") for c in cols]

bottom = 0
for count_i, label in zip(all_counts, all_labels):
    plt.bar(cols, count_i, 0.4, bottom=bottom, label=label)
    bottom += np.array(count_i)

# plt.xticks(np.arange(len(cols)) + 0.1, cols)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45, length=0)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: To have the bars in the same order as the legend, you could draw them starting from the top:

```py
bottom = np.sum(all_counts, axis=0)
for count_i, label in zip(all_counts, all_labels):
    bottom -= np.array(count_i)
    plt.bar(cols, count_i, 0.4, bottom=bottom, label=label)
```